# Button width issue

Tags: html, css

I just did an UL list with 4 LI elements and I did this in CSS:

```
ul li {
width:200px;/*problem*/
display:inline;
color:white;
background-color:red;
border-radius:5px;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:2em;
box-shadow:0 7px 0 #600;
padding:5px 20px;
margin:15px;
}
```

The problem is that the width property has no influency with the width of the li element, and if I want to do it larger I have to add padding to the right and left but that is not good because there are different lenghts in each box since some have more letters than others.

Why is that happening?

Thanks,

Comment: `display:inline-block;`

Comment: What the guy above me said ^ If you want to use the box model assigning things like width and padding properly you need to use it by using `display:inline-block` (if you want it inlined) or `display:block` if you want it to display like a proper block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set `block` type properties (i.e. width), you'll have to set the `display` to `inline-block` on the `li` element

```css
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The selector above will only affect the `li` element.  If you want to style child elements, like a button, you'll also have to set the width property there.

```css
ul li button {
    width:200px;
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkQpx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

All HTML elements are rendered in one of the following ways:

- **Block:** Takes up the full width available, or a defined width, with a new line before and after. This can be forced using `display:block;`
- **Inline:** Takes up only as much width as it needs, based on its contents, and does not force new lines. This can be forced using `display:inline;`
- **Not displayed:** Some tags, like `<meta />`, `<style>` and `<link>` are not visible. This can be forced using `display:none;`

Inline elements can not have a defined width. Only block element can do this. There is a way to have a block level element to be inline by using `display: inline-block`. This is much like an emoticon or an image would be displayed in a word document. You can define a width because it is a block, but it will fall inline with the rest of the elements if no width is set. Inline blocks will not respect line-heights, meaning that if an image is inline with text it will adjust the line-height to allow itself to fit inline.

Comment: You've simplified it somewhat. The allowed values for display include: none, block, inline, inline-block, list-item, marker, run-in, compact, table, inline-table, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group,  table-row, table-cell, table-caption. That's the list from FF, not including all the -moz-* values.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Though, in theory all elements can be considered block, inline or hidden. Other `display` values are just adding pseudo properties to the element. `display: table` acts as a block level table with pseudo properties that match tables. That's why there's a property for `display: inline-table`. The value for `run-in` is simply a pseudo-state display property that allows the element to act as either block or inline based on it's inherited state. Check out the spec for display, every value mentions either being block, inline or hidden http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked *why* this is happening - inline elements width is determined by their content so your width css has no effect. Setting the item to display as `inline-block` or `block` will make it determine it's width based on your styles rather than the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: inline-block` not `display: block;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/SyBBu/

```
ul li {
width:200px;/*problem*/
display:inline-block;
color:white;
background-color:red;
border-radius:5px;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:2em;
box-shadow:0 7px 0 #600;
padding:5px 20px;
margin:15px;
}
```